# Update the string value in the object based on the parameter - Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have exported an object in a separate ts file and I would like that to be parameterized

```
export const customer = {
  comment: 'Wow, this is great because {{username}} is doing what we needed' 
};
```

Then in another ts file, I get this constant but I want to pass the value of username

```
import * as customerConstants from 'constants';
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit{
 username ='learn' 
 customerData = customerConstants.customer ;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customerData.comment = customerData + username;
  }
```

I want to put learn in place of username in the customer const. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `customer.comment` is string you could use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace `'{{username}}'` with `username` variable value.